# Refreshing data from an API call

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller and a service roughly like these:

```
.controller('BooksCtrl', function($scope, bookService) {
     bookService.getBooks().then(function(response) {
       $scope.books = response.data;
    });
})

.factory('bookService', function($http) {
    return {
        getBooks: function() {
            return $http.get('http://books.com/books').success(function(response) {
                return response;
            });

        }
    }
})
```

Whenever I go to the route corresponding to the `BooksCtrl`, the list of books on my screen goes blank (while the `GET` call is running) and then re-draws with the fresh data.

What's a good way of avoiding this refresh on the page, keeping the existing data while the `GET` call is running and then just updating the screen?

I was thinking of keeping all the books in a property of `bookService`, assigning that to `$scope.books` in the controller and then only updating that property once the `GET` call completes (I'd call something like `bookService.updateBooks()` in the controller). Is this reasonable or is there easier/better way?

Comment: Is this behaviour happening "only" whenever you go to view corresponding to 'BooksCtrl' ? Or When you are on the same view and service call is updating data?

Comment: The service call is only made when the controller is run. There is nothing updating the data while the view/route is active.

Comment: See, when you navigate to a new view all the old data in the previous view  will go out of scope. New controller will come into scope and reloads all the data and builds view from scratch.

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if I could do something about it. Feed the view a cached list of books while I'm fetching a new list for example. I'm wondering if/how people do this.

Comment: I am thinking about other approaches. Your old view displays list of books and you need your new view to  display same list of books(without re-rendering) and include something more in this new view along with books... right? Can you show you .html pages for this old and new views? Probably, ng-include may come handy here but not sure until I try it out.

Comment: Depends on: how often data changes? how data changes? how big is that data? how much time takes to get data? etc. In each case different approach can be better - this is actually more business question than development.